# Firebase: Basic Account / User Role (notifications only)

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

In the FireBase Console for my Android app, is it possible to give a user a role that enables him/her to send notifications to the devices, and nothing more?

I tried the current "project roles", and none seem to suffice, they give the user too many functions.

If I set the most basic role "Project -> Viewer" the user cannot edit anything, but can still delete the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to give collaborators access to only a subset of the feature in the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can. Firebase made it possible for you to add a user with a specific role. This option is currently in beta but it works. I tested it just now. Firebase roles are divided by categories and you can assign user as an admin or viewer for a specific category. For a more detailed explanation just check the attachment.

[image]

Comment: still cant give only push notification access.